# Is there any org-babel source block that converts to a LaTeX pseudocode algorithm block?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, org-babel

Currently, when I want to add some algorithm's pseudocode to my LaTeX export, I have to manually write LaTeX:

```
** Pixel-Flipping: A Technique to Assess Faithfulness
- Pixel-flipping is a quantitative, empirical method to evaluate the faithfulness of explanations.
- It involves iteratively removing input features based on their importance and observing the impact on model predictions.
  - The resulting curves are called /Deletion Curves/.

#+BEGIN_SRC latex
\begin{algorithm}[H]

\caption{Pixel-Flipping}

\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE $pfcurve = []$
\FOR{$p$ in $argsort(-R)$}

\STATE $x \leftarrow x - \{x_p\}$ (remove pixel $p$ from the image)
\STATE $pfcurve.append(f(x))$

\ENDFOR
\RETURN $pfcurve$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
#+END_SRC
```

Is there a way I can just write the pseudocode in an org-babel source block (e.g., in Python), and it gets converted to a LaTeX algorithm block automatically?

Comment: Did you look at setting the `:results` to `latex`? Does that do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have the line `#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{algorithm2e}` at
the beginning of your `.org` file and then remove the lines
`#+BEGIN_SRC latex` and `#+END_SRC` from your algorithm snippet.
Then exporting to LaTeX/pdf will give you this:
[image]

Comment: The snippet I provided in the question is LaTeX already. I want to write in a Python-like language and export as LaTeX. I guess it's not possible.